# Question about $\aleph = 2^{\aleph_0}$ proof.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm reading this proof from my course's book for the identity: $\aleph = 2^{\aleph_0}$

The proof starts with the claim:  $2^{\aleph_0} \le \aleph \le 10^{\aleph_0}$.

Then, since $2^{\aleph_0} = 10^{\aleph_0}$ we conclude that $\aleph = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

I don't understand why can one claim a-priori the first assumption.

Comment: What is $\aleph?$

Comment: it's c (cantor)

Comment: @GitGud: It's the cardinal of the continuum.

Comment: Didn't know about that notation. Thank you both.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That seems like notation that could cause confusion, why is it so?

Comment: @naslundx: That was Cantor's original notation (well, after he came up with the $\aleph$ notation in general anyway). I agree it can be confusing, and I suspect this is one of the reasons you see it less often nowadays, but it's still a reasonably familiar notation (at least amongst set theorists, I suppose).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every real number $x$ in the interval $[0,1]$ choose a representation in base $10$, that is a sequence $a_i$ of digits in the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, such that $x=\sum\frac{a_i}{10^i}$.

Now we have an injection from $\Bbb R$ into $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}^\Bbb N$. Therefore $\aleph\leq10^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does the proof take for granted that I already know $2^{\aleph_0} \le \aleph$? (left-hand side of the inequalities).

Comment: Well, the Cantor set is the proof that $2^{\aleph_0}\leq\aleph$.

Comment: Unfortunately, we didn't learn about "Cantor set".

Comment: I guess I could use this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8314/mathfrakc-2-aleph-0

Comment: Unfortunate indeed. It's hard to say what you know and don't know.